# php image file upload and convert to base64 without saving image

Tags: php, image, upload, base64

I know how to upload image file and save to other location by using the following code. However, I need to do in such a way that user upload image and automatically convert to base64 without saving that image in my location. How should I do?

```
<?php
//print_r($_FILES);
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
    $errors=array();
    $allowed_ext= array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');
    $file_name =$_FILES['image']['name'];
 //   $file_name =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $file_ext = strtolower( end(explode('.',$file_name)));


    $file_size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    echo $file_tmp;echo "<br>";

    $type = pathinfo($file_tmp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $data = file_get_contents($file_ext);
    $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
    echo "Base64 is ".$base64;



    if(in_array($file_ext,$allowed_ext) === false)
    {
        $errors[]='Extension not allowed';
    }

    if($file_size > 2097152)
    {
        $errors[]= 'File size must be under 2mb';

    }
    if(empty($errors))
    {
       if( move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, 'images/'.$file_name));
       {
        echo 'File uploaded';
       }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($errors as $error)
        {
            echo $error , '<br/>'; 
        }
    }
   //  print_r($errors);

}
?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p>
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">

</p>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to happen after the image is converted to base64?

Comment: actually, for project, I want to save that base64 into database instead of saving image file.

Comment: Use `file_get_contents()` to get the contents of the temporary uploaded file, `base64_encode()` to encode it, `file_put_contents()` to save the file. Although storing a base64 encoded representation of an image file sounds like a bad idea - with big files, you may run into RAM problems, and the resulting file will be 33% larger than the original. Why do that?

Comment: Yes. I need to test with that one. If I writing like this, I can't get base64 string. Can you please guide me?  $type = pathinfo($file_tmp, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $data = file_get_contents($file_ext);
        $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' .     base64_encode($data);
        echo "Base64 is ".$base64;

Comment: That should be okay, what are you getting instead? (Note that for a perfect solution, you should detect the image type through more secure means than the file's extension, e.g. `getimagesize()`)

Comment: It is because I think I am using tempt directory of the image when user upload. So, I get this error. How should I change? Warning: file_get_contents(jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploadimage/index.php on line 21

Comment: What value is `$file_tmp`?

Comment: File tmp is /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpM1X4yo

Comment: `file_get_contents(jpg)` suggests that `$file_tmp` is not actually being used there. There must be a mistake somewhere.

Comment: oh..i have now put my full code in question. I don't know why $file_tmp is not used.

Comment: `file_get_contents($file_ext);` you're not using `$file_tmp`

Comment: opps...my mistake...thanks for helping me ..Pekka :D

Comment: No problem. You can consider deleting this question, as it was ultimately down to a syntax error

Comment: it should be okay... i also know now how to convert to base64 without saving image. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $file_ext );
```

This should be:

```
$data = file_get_contents( $file_tmp );
```

This should solve your problem.